# How to load a font file and use its font style in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

I can load the font file using this:

```
PrivateFontCollection _fonts = new PrivateFontCollection();
_fonts.AddFontFile ( filepath );
Font customFont = new Font(_fonts.Families[0], 6.0F);
```

But, the problem that I am facing is that I cannot load the font style (Bold/Italics etc) from the font file. 
I need the font file from the user, because I am going to save the font file and then use OpenGL to render it. But, before the actual rendering, I need to show a preview using WPF.

All the fonts can be assumed to be system fonts. But, I need to find out the font style from TTF file to show it on WPF Canvas. What I can actually do is that I can ask the user to load a font file as well as specify the style from the drop down, but that defeats the purpose, because if the user specifies a wrong style, then it will show differently on the emulator and during rendering.

So, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I completely understand your problem, but if you want to display some text in a particular font, then you can do it like this. First, add the font file into a folder in your project... let's say it's called `Resources`. Next, set its *Build Action* to *Content*. Then you can use that font in XAML like this:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="/Resources/#Some Font Name" Text="Some Font Name" />
```

Comment: 1) I need the exact font file for OpenGL.
2) So, I ask the user to choose font file
3) I can extract the font name from file.
4) I cannot extract font style info from file
5) But, font style has to be specified when creating a new font in c#
6) I need to find the font style

Comment: Ah... well this won't help you then. I'll leave it in case it helps anyone else in the future.

Comment: Any clue regarding this? It must be a common problem?

Comment: *It must be a common problem?*... I'm not so sure if it is.